# scalable SVG with fixed border size

Tags: html, css, svg, responsive

I am looking for a way to keep a fixed line width and keeping the svg responsive.

This is how it should look:
https://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/wMLBLK

However, the example above is established using CSS and I need to do it with the `<path>` element.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this via `<path stroke-width="2" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" ... />`, even though keep in mind that `vector-effect` is not implemented in IE10 or lower.

Have a look [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/stroke-width/) in case you need any further explanation or at [this](http://codepen.io/rlchy/pen/MaoJXQ) example.